# Not able to assign values to a column. Bag_of_words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I am trying to assign values to a column in my pandas df, however I am getting a blank column, here's the code:

```
df['Bag_of_words'] = ''
columns = ['genre', 'director', 'actors', 'key_words']


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    words = ''
    for col in columns:
        words += ' '.join(row[col]) + ' '
    row['Bag_of_words'] =words
```

[image]

The output is an empty column, can someone please help me understand what is happening here, as I am not getting any errors.

Comment: `iterrows` is not the right approach here. please provide an example of you input dataframe and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [`iterrows` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> 2. You should **never modify** something you are iterating over.
>    This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the
>    data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing
>    to it will have no effect.

So you do `row[...] = ...` and it turns out `row` is a copy and that's not affecting the original rows.

[`iterrows` is frowned upon anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9332187), so you can instead

- join each words list per row to become strings
- aggregate those strings with `" ".join` row-wise
- add space to them

```py
df["Bag_of_words"] = (df[columns].apply(lambda col: col.str.join(" "))
                                 .agg(" ".join, axis="columns")
                                 .add(" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
row['Bag_of_words'] =words
```

Use:

```
df.at[index,'Bag_of_words'] = words
```